# mySQL Count Content and auto +1

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to sort data from on this page: http://www.excelwrestling.com/sortbymostwinsbyweight.php

I want the table to be ordered by Weight and then the name with most wins in that weight.  Also, I would like to add one more column showing the number of wins for that wrestler.

This is what I having from looking at tutorials but they are not being ordered correctly:

```
$query="SELECT *,Winner, COUNT(*) as count FROM results GROUP BY Winner ORDER BY Weight ASC ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I should have explained better, on my webpage the results are showing up, but the wrestler with the most wins is not showing up on top of the weight.  The results are jumbled.

Comment: How do you want to sort the names? Alphabetically?

Comment: How do you store that a wrester won a match?

Comment: I want the names to be sorted by number of wins that person has.  So if Tom has 4 wins, and Abe has 1 win, Tom's name would be first, and so on.

Comment: @ypercube The user fills at a form at the tournament and chooses a name for a winner from a drop down box, then it goes in my results table.

Comment: So, you store the winner's name in the `Winner` column, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ww.*
FROM 
        ( SELECT Weight, Winner, COUNT(*) AS Wins 
          FROM results 
          GROUP BY Weight, Winner 
        ) AS ww
    JOIN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT Weight
          FROM results
        ) AS dw
            ON  ww.Weight = dw.Weight
            AND ww.Winner =
                ( SELECT r.Winner
                  FROM results AS r
                  WHERE r.Weight = dw.Weight
                  GROUP BY r.Winner 
                  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                ) ;
```

An index on `(Weight, Winner)` will help efficiency of the query.

---

You may get the correct result with this query, too, but I do not recommend it as it uses some non-standard features and behaviours of MySQL, and therefore could break in the future:

```
SELECT Weight, Winner, Wins
FROM 
        ( SELECT Weight, Winner, COUNT(*) AS Wins 
          FROM results 
          GROUP BY Weight, Winner 
          ORDER BY Weight, Wins DESC
        ) AS ww
GROUP BY Weight ;
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but I can't get it to work.  Also, I don't have anything set up for WINS.  I was hoping it would just give them a number automatically.

Comment: It does give you a number. I just aliased (named) it `Wins` instead of your `count`.

Answer (score -1):

You're ordering just by `winner`, when you say your requirements are by 'most wins'. That means you should have:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY Winner
ORDER BY Weight ASC, count DESC
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- order by the aggregate results.
```

Note that I'm assuming you want the weights in ascending order, and wins in descending order.